# Bullet List Override

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, cc-2014

I can't seem to create a Bulleted List in InDesign CC where the first line is not bulleted and do it as a Paragraph Style. I have a whole bunch of blocks of bulleted text which are basically menus. You can create complicated outlines with defined lists as long as you use Numbered Lists. Since the bullets are set at paragraph level, nested character styles won't overwrite just the first line. This seems simple, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Two paragraph styles... one for bullets one without.

Comment: but I need to be able to format the whole block with one click. I need to automate this project as much as possible

Comment: Seems to me that information should be part of the question if it's imperative.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, but that is what I meant by saying "do it as a Paragraph Style, " implying one Style and not two.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding what you are trying to accomplish - when you say "complicated outlines", you just are describing what you are doing, right? The only "outlines" feature I know of in InDesign is outlining fonts to convert to vector. Are you trying to use some automatic document structure outline feature I'm unaware of?

Comment: not that kind of outline. by outline I mean a list of items with different levels of indenting - outlining as a way to organize text items - not graphic outlines or converting fonts to vector outlines... I thought this would be simple so I didn't include any screenshots...

Answer (score 2):

You might make two different paragraph styles. One for the list and one for the heading.

I've also been known to make an additional paragraph style for the last item in the bulleted list with extra space after.

I'm not sure if this is the right answer, but I make mine with multiple paragraph styles.

Comment: need to be able to do it in one click.